# Nextjs API call recive binary file

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, file-upload

I'm still very new with developing in javascript en javascript frameworks and have a question about uploading files to an Next.js API endpoint.

What I want is to upload an image to audio file to an API endpoint, keep that file only in memory en send that data to an anther external API.

I need shooting like fs.readFileSync( path, options ) does, but then with a file that exists only in memory.

After sending it to the external API I will save it to Prisma.

Saving it to Prisma and uploading to the external API works

What is the samplers way to do this.

External API: https://docs.bundlr.network/developer-docs/sdk/api/upload

Code that does not work.

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method not allowed' });
    }

    const image: Buffer = req.body;

    const prisma = new PrismaClient();


    let updateArtwork = await prisma.artwork.findFirst({
        where: {
            AND: [
                { id: Number(req.query.artworkID) },
                { Artist: { some: { id: Number(req.query.artistID) } } },
            ],
        }
    });

    const network = process.env.BUNDLR_NETWORK;
    const currency = process.env.BUNDLR_CURRENCY;
    const providerUrl = process.env.BUNDLR_PROVIDER_URL;
    const privateKey = process.env.BUNDLR_PRIVATE_KEY;

    try {
        if (network !== undefined && currency !== undefined && providerUrl !== undefined && privateKey !== undefined) {
            const bundlr = new Bundlr(network, currency, privateKey, {
                providerUrl: providerUrl,
            });

            const price = await bundlr.getPrice(Number(image.size ?? 0));
            const priceConverted = bundlr.utils.fromAtomic(Number(image.size ?? 0));

            await bundlr.fund(price);

            const bundlrResponse = await bundlr.uploadFile(image);

            res.status(200).json({
                'address': bundlr.address,
                'currency': bundlr.currency,
                'price': price,
                'priceConverted': priceConverted,
                'bundlrResponse': bundlrResponse
            });

            if (updateArtwork === null) {

                const newArtwork = await prisma.artwork.create({
                    data: {
                        primaryColor: '#000',
                        secondaryColor: '#fff',
                        transactionID: bundlrResponse.id,
                        Artist: {
                            connect: {
                                id: Number(req.query.artistID),
                            },
                        },
                    },
                });
            } else {

            }



        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ 'errorMessage': 'Unable to upload image' });
    } finally {
        prisma.$disconnect();
    }
}
```